# Increasing Java memory for one app affects other apps negatively

Tags: java, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I'm not from Java background, but I need to work with an application that gives this very common out of memory error. I followed the steps in this link http://www.wikihow.com/Increase-Java-Memory-in-Windows-7 but instead of `-Xms`, I've used `-Xmx` to set only the max allocation rather than the initial allocation.

However, this affected other Java apps **negatively**. They simply don't start for no obvious reason.

I say ***other apps*** shouldn't be affected as long as they don't reach the limit and I know they can **never** reach the limit I set.

So, why are they affected?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the execution of your first JVM has left your PC without enough physical memory for another one.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple applications may use the same JVM (the one you change the allocation). If your others java applications have their own parameters for space allocation, then you might overwrite them by doing this, and thus, prevent them from starting (because they don't have enough, or too much, or not what they need).

You might want to try to set those parameter only for the application you need. You'll have to test with command line "java" to start your app, and set the parameters as command lines parameters.

Answer (score -1):

If you have installed a 32bit JDK use this VM memory args:

```
-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

otherwise use this:

```
-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

It works for me for all Apps (Project) that generated permgen error space